# JavaFx on Eclipse, impossibility loading .fxml

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I have created a new JavaFX project,and I can comfortably run.

Main:

```
package application; 

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If I try to copy and paste some my old `.fxml` I receive some error.

The fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="691.0" prefWidth="668.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ControllerStart">
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="599.0" prefWidth="668.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="366.0" layoutY="38.0" text="10:20">
               <font>
                  <Font size="62.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="359.0" layoutY="111.0" text="00:00:00">
               <font>
                  <Font size="48.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="66.0" text="Operator code:">
               <font>
                  <Font size="23.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="111.0" layoutY="101.0" text="000-000-00" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_smcProblem" disable="true" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="problem" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_smcCheck" disable="true" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="check" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_smc" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="221.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SMC_click" text="SMC" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_sketch" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="330.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sketch" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_sketchProblem" disable="true" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="problem" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_sketchCheck" disable="true" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="351.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="check" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_configuration" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="457.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Configuration" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_configurationProblem" disable="true" layoutX="207.0" layoutY="447.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="problem" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_configurationCheck" disable="true" layoutX="207.0" layoutY="478.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="check" />
            <Button fx:id="B_closed" disable="true" layoutX="249.0" layoutY="591.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Closed">
               <font>
                  <Font size="35.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_supportH" layoutX="366.0" layoutY="221.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Support on helicopter" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_qualityS" layoutX="364.0" layoutY="291.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quality support " />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_releaseD" layoutX="365.0" layoutY="362.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Release of documents" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_other" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="515.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Other" />
            <TextField fx:id="TF_other" editable="false" layoutX="483.0" layoutY="510.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="136.0" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="CB_requestC" layoutX="364.0" layoutY="426.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Request ciclie" />
            <Button layoutX="112.0" layoutY="613.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SMC_click" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This is the modification of main file:

```
        ...
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(); //old part
        root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Start.fxml")); //new part
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400); //old part
        ...
```

I have also added a class ControllerStart.java.

This is my error when i run the project now:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/eclipse/workspace/neon/TAP1/bin/application/Start.fxml:47

  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
  at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.TextField field application.ControllerStart.TF_other to javafx.scene.control.TextField
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error line which is helpful for you is:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Can not set java.awt.TextField field application.ControllerStart.TF_other to javafx.scene.control.TextField
```

Basically you have a field in your controller called `TF_other` which is an AWT `TextField` annotated with `@FXML`. You're probably mistakenly importing `java.awt.TextField` when you should be importing `javafx.scene.control.TextField`.

---

So funnily enough all of the code you posted is irrelevant and the code you didn't post is where the error is.